# how do i fix this ? ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be inherited from `kivymd.app.MDApp`

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, hot-reload

I just don't understand why it doesn't work . I'm trying to do a simple hot reload app with kaki / kivyMD , following a tutorial from YouTube https://youtu.be/_pwbZofoffI at 8:00 for the time code (sorry , I'm new to this )

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.factory import Factory as F

Window.size = 360,640

class UI(F.ScreenManager):
    Builder.load_file("layout.kv")

class Main(MDApp):
     def build(self):
         return UI()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Main().run()
```

live.py

```
from kaki.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory as F
import os

class Live(App):
    CLASSES = {
        "UI": "main"
    }

    KV_FILES = {
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"layout.kv")
    }

    AUTORELOADER_PATHS = [
        (".", {"recursive": True}),
    ]


    def build_app(self, first=False):
        return F.UI()

Live().run()
```

layout.kv

```
<UI>
    Screen:
        MDLabel:
            text: "hello"
```

I'm using the PyCharm Terminal: `set DEBUG=1 ; python live.py`

**The traceback**

```py
(venv) PS C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage> set DEBUG=1 ; python live.py

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in 

C:\Users\Cipher\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-07-30_22.txt

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1 

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5 

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at 

"C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at 
"C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\Scripts\python.exe"

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system

[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 30.0.101.1340'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 620'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 30.0.101.1340'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>

[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider

[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06 (installed at "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

[WARNING] [Lang        ] The file 
C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\layout.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors.

 --- Logging error ---

 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kaki\app.py", line 163, in rebuild

     self.approot = self.build_app()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\live.py", line 19, in build_app
     return F.UI()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 973, in __init__
     super(ScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 366, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 540, in apply
     self._apply_rule(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 658, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\label.py", line 324, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\theming.py", line 1129, in __init__
     raise ValueError(

 ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be inherited from `kivymd.app.MDApp`

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1083, in emit
     msg = self.format(record)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 927, in format
     return fmt.format(record)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py", line 291, in format
     record = copy.deepcopy(record)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
     y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
     state = deepcopy(state, memo)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
     y = copier(x, memo)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
     y = copier(x, memo)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in _deepcopy_tuple
     y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in <listcomp>
     y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
     rv = reductor(4)

 TypeError: cannot pickle 'traceback' object

 Call stack:

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\live.py", line 21, in <module>

     Live().run()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run

     self._run_prepare()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare

     root = self.build()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kaki\app.py", line 101, in build

     self.rebuild(first=True)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kaki\app.py", line 168, in rebuild

     Logger.exception("{}: Error when building app".format(self.appname))
 Message: 'Live: Error when building app'

 Arguments: ()

 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\live.py", line 21, in <module>

     Live().run()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run

     self._run_prepare()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare

     root = self.build()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kaki\app.py", line 101, in build

     self.rebuild(first=True)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kaki\app.py", line 163, in rebuild

     self.approot = self.build_app()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\live.py", line 19, in build_app

     return F.UI()

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 973, in __init__
     super(ScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 366, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 540, in apply
     self._apply_rule(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 658, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\label.py", line 324, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\Cipher\PycharmProjects\AppliStage\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\theming.py", line 1129, in __init__
     raise ValueError(

 ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be inherited from `kivymd.app.MDApp`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 0):

As I can't quite tell alot about this but it seems to be cause by your class Live which inherits from App when it should be inheriting from MDApp.

```
class Live(App):
```

to

```
class Live(MDApp):
```

..